# why i am getting org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments?

Tags: java, junit4, powermock, powermockito

Currently, i am using the following dependency for my project But i am getting   org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments not found

please look on the dependency,

```
     <properties>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <powermock.version>1.7.0RC2</powermock.version>
     </properties>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
          <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
           <version>1.9.5</version>
            </dependency>


           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
           </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
         <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito-common</artifactId>     
         <version>1.6.5</version>
         </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-   module-junit4 -->
          <dependency>
          <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
          <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
          <version>${powermock.version}</version>
          </dependency>
```

End the error is during building the project using maven framework.

```
cannot access    org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments
 [ERROR] class file for                   org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments not found
```

Comment: You have faced with one of defect that has been introduced when we have tried to add supporting Mockito 2.x without fully rewriting code. Please, create an issue in our issue tracker on GitHub.

Comment: I am facing same isssue, How to resolve above issue ?