# Null pointer exception when jenkins version is set to 2.X

Tags: jenkins, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a plugin with jenkins version set to 1.580.3.And when I upgrade the jenkins version to 1.642.3<=version , it is throwing a null pointer exception.Below is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at hudson.model.Label.hashCode(Label.java:528)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
        at java.util.Collections.addAll(Collections.java:5401)
        at com.google.common.collect.Sets.newHashSet(Sets.java:183)
        at com.ericsson.oss.axis.ATest.setUp(ATest.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
```

below is my code

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.LabelParameterValue;
import org.mockito.Answers;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import com.XXXXX.JenkinsUtils;(internal)
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild;
import hudson.model.Label;
import hudson.model.ParameterValue;
import hudson.model.ParametersAction;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
        @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
        @PrepareForTest( JenkinsUtils.class)
            public class A{
                 @Mock
                private Label label;
                @Mock
                private Jenkins jenkins;
                @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
                private AbstractBuild build;


                @Before
                public void setUp() {
                    PowerMockito.mockStatic(JenkinsUtils.class);
                    try {
                        doReturn(Sets.newHashSet(label)).when(jenkins).getLabels();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(NodeLabelParameterUtils.class )    
    public class B{
           private BaselineDefinedMessageDispatcher unit;
            private BuildData buildData = new BuildData();
            private MyBuildDetails myBuildDetails;

            @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
            private AbstractBuild build;
            @Mock
            private BuildLogger buildLogger;
            @Mock
            private Label label;
            @Mock
            private Computer computer;
            @Mock
            private PretendSlave node;
            @Mock
            private FreeStyleProject project;
            @Mock
            private Jenkins jenkins;
            @Mock
            private EnvironmentVariableResolver envVarsResolver;


            @Before
            public void setUp() throws IOException, InterruptedException, Descriptor.FormException {
                unit = spy(new BaselineDefinedMessageDispatcher(null, null));
                unit.setBuildLogger(mock(BuildLogger.class));

                MyBuildDetails = mock(MyBuildDetails.class);

                doReturn("expectedSlaveHost").when(unit).getHostNameFromSlave(any(Node.class));
                doReturn(project).when(build).getProject();
                doReturn(Sets.<Node>newHashSet(node)).when(label).getNodes();
                doReturn(node).when(build).getBuiltOn();
                doReturn(jenkins).when(unit).getJenkinsInstance();

                doReturn(Sets.newHashSet(label)).when(jenkins).getLabels();

                PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);

                when(envVarsResolver.processString(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                        return (String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
                    }
                });
        }
```

The following dependencies are being used

```
        powermock-api-mockito - 1.6.3
        mockito-core          - 1.9.5
        junit                 - 4.11
        java                  - 1.8
        jenkins.version       - 1.642.3
```

I get the error exactly at  doReturn(Sets.newHashSet(label)).when(jenkins).getLabels(); in class A.
This is a maven project and when jenkins version is set to 1.580.3 mvn clean install is success but when it is version>=1.642.3 it is failing.
My aim is to upgrade jenkins verison to 2.X.I went through manyworkarounds in stackoverflow but nothing worked
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is the relation between class `A` and `B`. I would assume that class `B` is your real unit test and you didn't annote it properly. I also assume that the class `A` you mock in class `B` is not the one you have provided (why would you try to mock a UnitTest class in your test-code?). In any case you want to check your annotations and in doubt update the question.

Comment: Hi @second.I have edited the code.Does initializing really required .I doubt because this is working with jenkins version 1.580.3.I fillowed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253748/error-in-junit-while-mocking and is indeed throwing me ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/api/mockito/expectation/WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments  error

Comment: Afaik if you do not use the runner provided by mockito you need to use the init method. A `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that some dependency is missing in your classpath, you may want to provide the stacktrace.

Comment: its actually a error: cannot access WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments that is it.I am kind of stuck here.From suggestions I changed powermock-api-mockito-common version to 1.6.6 from 1.6.5 but nothing worked out

Comment: Might be an bug in the related version, found this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091594/why-i-am-getting-org-powermock-api-mockito-expectation-withorwithoutexpectedargu) mentioning the same error, You might need to try different versions.

Comment: I tried many combinations but nothing worked

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that produces the exception, including the import statements and the pom? I tried to get yours to run but as I am missing most of the classes and had to guess the imports for the others (`hudson.model.*`?) I can't really try it myself.

Comment: Hi @second I have added my import modules

Comment: Sorry, seems I was to focused on the not compiling components. I've updated my answer regarding the NPE. I am still not able to reproduce the other exception. You really need to provide a [mre] for this one (if its still relevant) and it might be better if you put it into a seperate question (so it would be a more specific question and might be able to gather more attention than this one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Looks like my orignal answer was just incorrect.

The NPE comes from the fact that the abstract `Label` class has a constructor parameter called `name`. This parameter is used to calculate the hashcode of the label.

If you mock it this `name` is `null` and you get the NPE.

The question now is do you need to create a mock of this or can you actually use a real instance? In the exmaple below I just used one of the implementations of that class `LabelAtom`. If a mock is required because you need to define some behaviour on the object that you can not get otherwise, you probably have to use a `spy`.

(Tested with `org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.85`)

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import hudson.model.Label;
import hudson.model.labels.LabelAtom;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    private Jenkins jenkins;

    private Label label;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        Assert.assertNotNull(jenkins);

        label = new LabelAtom("someName");

        // or if a mock is required
        //label = Mockito.spy(new LabelAtom("someName"));

        doReturn(Sets.newHashSet(label)).when(jenkins).getLabels();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

---

Regarding the `WithOrWithoutExpectedArguments` I was not able to reproduce that one.

Comment: My code is working when jenkins version is set to 1.580.3,powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1,mockito-core:1.9.5,junit 4.11.BTW it is maven project

Comment: WithorWithoutExpectedArgumenets is not required if null pointer exception is resolved.From the above solution yo provided I see there is no mocking .But all my test cases are dependent on mocking .I changed the way you suggested but there is an error from the dependet test cases like org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:

Comment: `NotAMockException` is normally thrown when you try to pass something into the `when` statement that is not a mock. If a mock is required try using the spy: `label = Mockito.spy(new LabelAtom("someName"))`. If that does not help you need to provide more infromation ([mre] once more).

Comment: Hi @Second,I somehow removed  PowerMockito.mockStatic(JenkinsUtils.class); and replaced with  Label label = new LabelAtom("label");    assertNotNull(jenkins); and this is not throwong me any exception .BUt if you look my public class B above  doReturn(Sets.<Node>newHashSet(node)).when(label).getNodes();       doReturn(node).when(build).getBuiltOn(); am getting errors saying not a mock.Can you make my class B run

Comment: If thats the change you did, you can't use it in the `when`. However when you use a `spy` (check the answer (`\\or if a mock is required`) and my previous comment again and that should not be an issue).

Comment: HI @Second.Thanks for the code it is working but I have another method which is failing  PowerMockito.when(JenkinsUtils.getJenkinsInstance()).thenReturn(jenkins);
        assertThat(NodeLabelParameterUtils.getLabel(this.label.toString()).toString(), is("label"));.I get the error saying jenkins instance is undefined.Jenkins utils is my own class which creates jenkins instance using Jenkins j = Jenkins.getInstance();.Help me solving this

Comment: Please add a new question, providing more details abouts your JenkinsUtil class and the stacktrace you are facing.